# a-frame wont load own 3d model

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, aframe

I am new to A-frame, and I am trying to display a 3d model on a marker. When I place a box it works, but when I try to import my own 3d model, it doesn't show.

```
<!-- include A-Frame obviously -->
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.6.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<!-- include ar.js for A-Frame -->
<script src="https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
<body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
  <a-scene embedded arjs>
    <!-- create your content here. just a box for now -->
    <a-box position='0 0.5 0' material='opacity: 0.5;'></a-box>

<!-- define your gltf asset -->
<a-assets>
  <a-asset-item id="tree" src="models/scene.gltf"></a-asset-item>
</a-assets>
<!-- use your gltf model -->
<a-entity gltf-model="##tree"></a-entity>


    <!-- define a camera which will move according to the marker position -->
    <a-marker-camera preset='hiro'></a-marker-camera>
  </a-scene>
</body>
```

Comment: FWIW, Your selector is wrong, It’s `#tree` not `##tree`

Comment: You're also using an old version of A-Frame. Use 0.8.2